# Validação Formulário ASP.NET em Tabs Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Possuo um formulário em `ASP.NET` com seu conteúdo dividido em Tabs do Bootstrap. Porém, alguns desses campos são obrigatórios (Required) ou são do `type="number"` e `"email"`, caso eles não estejam de acordo, ao enviar o formulário vai aparecer uma mensagem de do `HTML5` pedindo para fazer o preenchimento correto. Porém, como estou trabalhando com tabs, só consigo ver as mensagens caso eu esteja na aba onde ela está sendo exibida.

Existe alguma forma de, através do `JavaScript` abrir a aba correspondente quando algum de seus campos for obrigatório ou estiver preenchido incorretamente?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode identificar os elementos com erro pela "class", como você está utilizando bootstrap creio que a classe seja "has-error".

Identificando os elementos você poderá identificar qual aba eles pertencem por meio da função closest do jQuery https://api.jquery.com/closest/.

```
var $elemError = $('.has-error:first');

if($elemError[0]){
    var $tabError = $elemError.closest('.tab-pane');
    var tabErrorId = $tabError.attr('id');  

    $('[href=#' + tabErrorId + ']').tab('show');
}
```

Comment: Para funcionar melhor em todas as situações, sugiro decorar todas as abas com erros com algum detalhe em vermelho e colocar o foco na primeira.